# Animate background opacity of *any* wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf

I want an effect where I can animate the background opacity of any GroupBox control.
This would give me additional visual notification if something changes - I can flash the control to indicate the new status.

I have

```
private void ToggleBackgroundFade(Control control)
{
    var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation { From = 1.0, To = 0.0, Duration = new Duration(duration) };
    // new brush because old one is frozen
    control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xD6, 0xEF, 0xD1));
    control.Background.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
}

private void KickoffFlashingAnimation(Control controlToFade)
{
    controlToFade.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
        ToggleBackgroundFade(controlToFade))
    );
}
```

and all with style

```
<Style x:Key="GroupBoxHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00D6EFD1" />
</Style>
```

so I want to pass any GroupBox to the KickoffFlashingAnimation() method.

It runs fine, with no errors, but the groupbox doesn't change color after initially being set to the light green #ffd6efd1..
Any tips?

Comment: I do not really know that "control" has a property of "Background" but maybe it does not change the color because you've missed "control.BackColor"? I'm just guessing :)

Comment: Might want to ad the if(controlToFade is GroupBox) { } check, unless you want other controls to respond

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried your above code and it worked fine for Groupbox with me.There might be issue with your Groupbox that all of its Content area is filled with other controls that ultimately hide its Background.So just to test it you can give your GroupBox.Content more Width than that of Controls within it and then try to run with your above animation code by passing the instance of the GroupBox.I hope this will help.

Comment: I generally have a few (label) controls in the GroupBox, but all with transparent backgrounds. Thanks for the tip..